# what is wrong in this command ....can you please locate the error in this command

Tags: shell, unix, syntax-error, variable-assignment

```
 orig_file = PRC_19_000011061354_01147_20110323.gz
 $( print $orig_file | cut -d"_" -f4 )
```

I need the answer as 01147 which is the fourth field...

Comment: also, remove the `$()` on the second line. cut returns 01147, and then you're trying to execute that as a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the spaces around `=` in

```
orig_file = PRC_19_000011061354_01147_20110323.gz
```

and replace `print` with `echo`.

Comment: THANKS >>>GOT IT

CAN I KNOW WHAT IS CHECK_ret

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. You have to remove the spaces around = to make the variable assignment work, though.

Comment: can you please explain what is the meaning of below command  ...                                                          check_ret "Extract of rec count from filename $orig_file" quiet

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
orig_file=PRC_19_000011061354_01147_20110323.gz
$(echo $orig_file | cut -d"_" -f4)
```